# Datamapper's first_or_create equivalent in sequel?

Tags: ruby, datamapper, sequel

Is there a native Sequel way to implement Datamapper's `first_or_create` method?

Or am I bound to combine selects and inserts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [find_or_create](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sequel/Sequel/Model/ClassMethods#find_or_create-instance_method) should work for you.

> Like find but invokes create with given conditions when record does
>   not exist. Unlike find in that the block used in this method is not
>   passed to find, but instead is passed to create only if find does not
>   return an object.